# Three.js scene in ExtJS Panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, three.js

I didn't manage to get a Three.js scene rendered in an ExtJS panel.
Does anyone know about some demo code for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out, so I am going to answer my own question as this may help others.

Having the ExtJS panel defined like this:

```
xtype : 'panel',
id : '3dviewer',
region : 'center',
layout : 'fit'
```

And the Three.js WebGL renderer like this:

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias : true
});
renderer.setSize(width, height);
```

The renderer dom element can be added to the panel like this:

```
Ext.getCmp('3dviewer').body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

Comment: is there an example for integrating threejs and extjs ?